# why is my django render function not returning correct output

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a render function which has the below arguments. This gives me the correct output on the directed page.

```
return render(request, 'about_experiment.html', {'researcher': researcher})
```

But when i include another argument, it does not do the work for it as the study output is not coming

```
return render(request, 'about_experiment.html', {'researcher': researcher}, {'study': study})
```

where am i going wrong

Comment: I got it guys thanks. return render(request, 'about_experiment.html', {'researcher': researcher, 'study': study})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
return render(request, 'about_experiment.html', {'researcher': researcher, 'study': study})
```

Because django render function

`render(request, template_name, context=None, content_type=None, status=None, using=None)`.

Here context is dict.